# How to open vuejs datepicker on field focus?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-datepicker

The vuejs datepicker opens only when I click on its input field. I want it to pop up when I focus on its field by pressing tab from the previous field.

I looked for solutions on stackoverflow but could not find anything similar.

Here is my code:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   vuejsDatepicker
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Textbox" autofocus>
  <br><br>
  <vuejs-datepicker placeholder="Datepicker"></vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
```

Whenever I press tab after writing something on the textbox, the focus goes to the datepicker field but the picker only pops up when I click on it using mouse. Whereas I want it to open everytime on focus.
Can someone help please?

Comment: Trigger click on focus?

Comment: [How to open the datepicker on focus and hide on blur #560](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/issues/560)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the source.. The focus event is not bound so you may open an issue about that. But you can achieve the effect the following way:

```
<datepicker ref="dp1" @focusin.native="onfocusin"></datepicker>
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
    onfocusin(){
        setTimeout((ev)=>{
            this.$refs.dp1.isOpen || this.$refs.dp1.showCalendar(ev);
        }, 50)
    }
}
```

Another option is to modify the plugin a via `mixin` where you can modify the `showCalendar` method that currently toggles the visibility of the calendar to only allow it to open the calendar:

```
let myDatepicker = {
    mixins: [datepicker],

    methods: {
        showCalendar(){
            if(this.isOpen) return;

            return datepicker.showCalendar.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This works well for focus but does not work properly on click. When I click on the datepicker field, the calendar pop up shows for 1 second and then hides.

Comment: You can move the logic into a method and make proper checks before trying to open the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced some issues with the suggested mixin, I have modified it and provided a complete working example below.

If the user clicks or tabs to the field they will not see a flicker and the calendar will only open once.

```
<template>
    <toggleDatepicker
        ref="datepicker"
        @focusin.native="showCalendar"
        />    
</template>
<script>
    import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
    let toggleDatepicker = {
        mixins: [Datepicker],
        methods: {
            showCalendar(){
                if(this.isOpen) return;
                return Datepicker.methods.showCalendar.apply(this);
            }
        }
    };

    export default {
        components: {toggleDatepicker},
        methods: {
            showCalendar() {
                this.$refs.datepicker.$children[0].$emit('showCalendar')
            },
        },

    }
</script>
```

This is based on:

- vuejs-datepicker: ^1.6.2